# How to prevent my client from hanging when exit is typed?

Tags: c, sockets, client-server, telnet, kill

I am trying to implement a telnet like application where the user can connect to someone else's machine remotely. I have both server and client codes, but I feel like my client code is where I am wrong at. When user types "exit" I want my client to exit and get back to my working directory, but it doesn't. It hangs indefinitely. So I am posting only some code instead of posting the entire thing and also I have removed some error checking just for the sake of question here.

```
pid_t pid = fork();
switch(pid)
{
    case -1: 
        error("Client: Error in forking.\n");
    break;
    case 0: // We are in the child process
    {
        char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int nread;
        // Read from the terminal/stdin and write to the socket
        while((nread = read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0)
        {
            int result = write(sockfd, buffer, nread); 
            if(result == -1)
            {
                error("Error while writing to socket\n");
            }
        } // end while
    } // end child

} // end switch

// Parent Read from the socket and write to the terminal/stdout
int nRead;
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
while((nRead = read(sockfd, buffer, 512)) > 0)
{
    int result = write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, nRead);
    if(result == -1)
    {
        error("Client: Error while writing to stdout from socket.\n");
    }
} // end while

kill(pid, SIGKILL);
close(sockfd);
// Wait for child to end before the parent
wait(NULL);
```

So basically after forking,

My child process will do this : read from terminal/stdin and write to the socket.

My parent will do this: read from the socket and write to the terminal or stdout.

The problem is that when I type exit, I want the child process to die since there is nothing else to write to the socket(since I want to close the connection with the server), but the kill statement never gets executed. I put a printf before to check that. I feel that the while loop before kill statement is infinite, if so, what to do to stop it.

Comment: Where do you check for the "exit" input?

Comment: When my client gets connected to server, it execs bash on the server. So now I am interacting with the server's bash, not mine. Once I type exit, that bash ends and I should get my computer's prompt back, but the client hangs.

Comment: "When my client gets connected to server, it execs bash on the server". That's rather important info that you should be providing up front don't you think? Show how you have implemented that. We can't help you unless you provide a [mcve].

Comment: you need to actually `exit()` the child, when finished processing in the child function.  The posted code is falling out of the child loop, into the parent loop.

Comment: There is NOTHING in the posted code about checking for a client receiving `exit` from the terminal.   So your question has nothing to do with the posted code.  Please post a MCVE.

Comment: the `error()` function, found in the header file: `error.h` does not have the syntax of your posted code.  The correct syntax is: `void error(int status, int errnum, const char *format, ...);`